# Parse all XML files in a directory Python

Tags: python, parsing, xml-parsing

Hi I'm trying to parse all XML files in a given directory using python. I am able to parse one file at a time but that would be 'impossible' for me to do due to the large number of files i.e. it works when I pre-define the tree and root, however not when I try to run for all the code.

This is what I implemented so far:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
directory = "C:/Users/danie/Desktop/NLP/blogs/"

def clean_dir(directory):
    path = os.listdir(directory)
    print(path) 
    for filename in path:
        tree = ET.parse(filename)
        root = tree.getroot()
        doc_parser(root)


post_list = []
def doc_parser(root):
    for child in root.findall('post'):
        post_list.append(child.text)

clean_dir(directory)
print(post_list[0])
```

The error I'm getting as follows:

```
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\Deep Learning New\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-91-fce6b0119ea7>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/danie/Desktop/NLP/blogs/Parser_Tes.py', wdir='C:/Users/danie/Desktop/NLP/blogs')

  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\Deep Learning New\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\Deep Learning New\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/danie/Desktop/NLP/blogs/Parser_Tes.py", line 19, in <module>
    clean_dir(directory)

  File "C:/Users/danie/Desktop/NLP/blogs/Parser_Tes.py", line 9, in clean_dir
    tree = ET.parse(filename)

  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\Deep Learning New\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1196, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)

  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\Deep Learning New\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 597, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)

  File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 103, column 225
```

In terms of printing out the path, all correct filenames are being printed out. Some of which are:

```
['1000331.female.37.indUnk.Leo.xml', '1000866.female.17.Student.Libra.xml', '1004904.male.23.Arts.Capricorn.xml', '1005076.female.25.Arts.Cancer.xml', '1005545.male.25.Engineering.Sagittarius.xml', '1007188.male.48.Religion.Libra.xml', '100812.female.26.Architecture.Aries.xml', '1008329.female.16.Student.Pisces.xml', '1009572.male.25.indUnk.Cancer.xml', '1011153.female.27.Technology.Virgo.xml', '1011289.female.25.indUnk.Libra.xml', '1011311.female.17.indUnk.Scorpio.xml', '1013637.male.17.RealEstate.Virgo.xml', '1015252.female.23.indUnk.Pisces.xml', '1015556.male.34.Technology.Virgo.xml', '1016560.male.41.Publishing.Sagittarius.xml', '1016738.male.26.Publishing.Libra.xml', '1016787.female.24.Communications-Media.Leo.xml', '1019224.female.27.RealEstate.Libra.xml', '1019622.female.24.indUnk.Aquarius.xml', '1019710.male.16.Student.Pisces.xml', '1021779.female.25.indUnk.Scorpio.xml', '1022037.male.23.indUnk.Cancer.xml', '1022086.female.17.Student.Cancer.xml', '1024234.female.17.indUnk.Libra.xml', '1025783.female.17.Student.Gemini.xml', '1026164.female.23.Education.Aries.xml', '1026443.female.15.Student.Scorpio.xml', '1028027.female.16.indUnk.Libra.xml', '1028257.male.26.Education.Aries.xml', '1029959.male.17.indUnk.Aries.xml', '1031806.male.17.Technology.Sagittarius.xml', '1032153.male.27.Technology.Pisces.xml', '1032591.female.24.Banking.Aquarius.xml', '1032824.female.15.Student.Libra.xml', '1034874.female.43.Publishing.Capricorn.xml', '1039136.male.24.Student.Capricorn.xml', '1039908.female.16.indUnk.Gemini.xml', '1040084.male.17.indUnk.Taurus.xml', '1042993.male.15.Student.Sagittarius.xml', '1043329.male.23.Government.Pisces.xml', '1043569.male.26.indUnk.Virgo.xml', '1043785.female.26.Biotech.Leo.xml', '1044338.female.23.Student.Leo.xml', '1045289.female.25.Arts.Aquarius.xml', '1045316.male.27.Non-Profit.Capricorn.xml', '1045831.male.23.Student.Libra.xml', '1046946.female.25.Arts.Virgo.xml', '1047241.male.16.indUnk.Aries.xml', '1050060.female.24.Student.Pisces.xml', '1051122.female.17.Student.Libra.xml', '1052611.male.23.Student.Aries.xml', '1054833.female.24.indUnk.Scorpio.xml', '1055228.female.16.Student.Cancer.xml', '1056232.female.17.indUnk.Aquarius.xml', '1056581.female.26.indUnk.Leo.xml', ....]
```

So I took the advice of both @wundermahn and @Kevin and use try...except. This is the output now. i.e. 482 from 19320 items. The issue now, when I try to print out a certain element from the list `post_list[]`. I'm getting the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Files with errors:

```
ERROR ON FILE: 669116.female.26.indUnk.Gemini.xml
ERROR ON FILE: 669514.female.27.indUnk.Sagittarius.xml
ERROR ON FILE: 669656.female.23.Advertising.Aries.xml
ERROR ON FILE: 669719.male.26.Science.Taurus.xml
ERROR ON FILE: 669764.female.17.indUnk.Sagittarius.xml
ERROR ON FILE: 670277.female.27.Education.Sagittarius.xml
ERROR ON FILE: 670314.male.24.indUnk.Leo.xml
ERROR ON FILE: 670684.male.24.Student.Libra.xml
ERROR ON FILE: 671748.male.27.Communications-Media.Aries.xml
ERROR ON FILE: 673093.male.27.Construction.Scorpio.xml
ERROR ON FILE: 673235.male.37.Internet.Capricorn.xml
ERROR ON FILE: 67459.male.34.Arts.Capricorn.xml
ERROR ON FILE: 674684.female.23.Religion.Libra.xml
```

Further checked and printed out `post_list`, for some reason the data is not being appended and it is empty.

Thanks again!

Comment: Looks like one of your files isn't parsing properly. Try putting `print(filename)` right before your `ET.parse` line. See which filename is the last one printed before crashing, open that file with a text editor, and see if there's anything strange near line 103 column 225.

Comment: @Kevin see the edit

Comment: @xalalau, if the problem is with your postings list, feel free to post another question. There are some of us (myself included!) that are really into information retrieval questions. If my answer below fixed the initial issue, which it looked like it did, please accept it so that others may use it in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin was correct in his comment that this error relates to the [`ElementTree` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) not being able to parse the document correctly. Something is not "true `XML`", and it could be something as simple as just an odd, non-unicode character or something.

What you can try to do to help debug is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
directory = "C:/Users/danie/Desktop/NLP/blogs/"

def clean_dir(directory):
    path = os.listdir(directory)
    print(path) 
    for filename in path:
        try:
            tree = ET.parse(filename)
            root = tree.getroot()
            doc_parser(root)
        except:
            print("ERROR ON FILE: {}".format(filename))


post_list = []
def doc_parser(root):
    for child in root.findall('post'):
        post_list.append(child.text)

clean_dir(directory)
print(post_list[0])
```

Adding in a [`try...except`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) statement will try each of the files, and if there is an error, print out which file is causing the error.

I don't have any data to test, but this should fix the error.

Comment: This answer should never have been accepted in it's current form - this "exception handling" with a too wide try clause and a bare except clause is an anttipattern and is actually __worse__ than no exception handling at all.

Comment: And as a matter of fact, it DID cause another issue for the OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59369448/xml-files-not-being-parsed-and-appended-to-list