# XML files not being parsed and appended to list

Tags: python, arrays, parsing, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse all XML files in a given directory using python. I am able to parse one file at a time but that would be 'impossible' for me to do due to the roughly 19k different xml files, i.e. it works when I pre-define the tree and the root, however not when I try to run for all the code. This post is in correlation to what I asked yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59360965/parse-all-xml-files-in-a-directory-python?noredirect=1#comment104919744_59360965)

This is what I implemented so far:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
directory = "C:/Users/danie/Desktop/NLP/blogs/"

def clean_dir(directory):
    path = os.listdir(directory)
    print(path) 
    for filename in path:
        try:
            tree = ET.parse(filename)
            root = tree.getroot()
            doc_parser(root)
        except:
            print("ERROR ON FILE: {}".format(filename))


post_list = []
def doc_parser(root):
    for child in root.findall('post'):
        post_list.append(child.text)

clean_dir(directory)
print(post_list[0])
```

So after I took the advice from the previous post by both @wundermahn and @Kevin to use try...except. This is the output now. i.e. 482 from 19320 items have an error however the supposedly good ones are not 'working'. The issue now, when I try to print out a certain element from the list post_list[]. I'm getting the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Further more, I checked and printed out `post_list`, and for some reason the data is not being appended and it is empty.

Sample XML:

```
<Blog>

<date>05,July,2003</date>
<post>


       B-Logs: The Business Blogs Paradox    urlLink HindustanTimes.com  discusses the effects of technology and blogs in particular. According to the article, Blogs are 'a direct, one-to-many vehicle for communicating ideas'. What makes them disruptive in business application is that they allow businesses - which are after all human -- to communicate with a human 'real voice'. On the other hand,  urlLink Webpronews.com  discusses the idea of corporate newsletter publishing via blogs. I found the idea very pragmatic and futuristic. Way to go !!


</post>

<date>04,July,2003</date>
<post>


       Bohemian Rhapsody : Is it??   I have just come back to my room from the  urlLink IIT  coffee shack. The place, where we have shared laughters and joys, sat for long hours over countless cups of coffee and maggi and chat sessions. Where we have shared our thoughts and fought over stupid topics discussing them passionately. I have just come back from that very place, but with thoughts and feelings so different from what it used to be.  Today the laughter has given way to a look of tension and frustration on everyone's face. "Its so frustrating. There is no job. I am applying everywhere. No vacancies." And then on the next table you hear, "I am planning to go abroad on a scholarship. The job scene is really bad and I don't think I will get a nice job. Going for higher studies is the only option left in front of me." And then a person comes who does have a job. Meeting him, I congratulate him. But he is too irritated with the job he got. The job is in a core engineering one, in a chemical MNC, but the pay is a punitive six thousand bucks; the only perk being free accomodation in some small village-town.  There are ruminations galore, about the uncertain futures. About the decisions made. About the hard work, before and during IIT years. And to end thus, with a degree in hand but no job to do justice to years of hardships and hardwork, and that too when you are the product of one of the best institutes in the country. It gets too disappointing.  I only wish those people, my dear friends, good luck !! May serendipity happen !!


</post>

<date>03,July,2003</date>
<post>


       Entrepreneur Guidelines    urlLink EntreWorld  is a website for entrepreneurs. It is a resourceful site for budding start-ups, discussing various dos and donts and giving practical advise for all stages of a start-up life cycle.    urlLink Auren Hoffman 's recent article on Entrepreneurial Boards discusses the leadership engine for the evolutionary stages of a start-up.   "Boards of advisors are best for helping entrepreneurs build companies in the formative stage, whereas boards of directors lend a hand during times of crisis or change, writes a serial entrepreneur."  Read the full article  urlLink here .  A strong board of directors can make the difference between success and failure for a start-up company. And, an effective advisory board can help one recruit those directors. Specific examples, indicating the tasks a board can accomplish and the skills it can bring to them, make this article particularly enlightening. The  urlLink article  can be assumed to be a Business 101 course :)).   Further, here is a  urlLink business plan  guide.


</post>

<date>02,July,2003</date>
<post>


       Business Profiles of Some Companies    urlLink Business Profiles Home Page  makes an informative reading. Biz/ed have created profiles for a range of business organisations. These are presented as sets of FAQs, grouped into themes.The companies profiled vary from McDonlad's to easyJet.   *How much does it cost to set up your own pizza delivery    franchise?  *What's the best way of promoting online gambling?  *How do the major supermarket retailers compete?  *Is it possible to run a professional football club as a private investment?  Answers to these questions and many more can be found on the  urlLink Site .


</post>

<date>02,July,2003</date>
<post>


       Multiple Interviews for One Job: The present-day scenario.    urlLink csmonitor.com  published an article on the 12-step job interview. There was a time when the recruiter took 20 minutes to size you up and skim your résumé before leaping to his feet and barking, 'Kid, I like the cut of your jib. Welcome aboard!'. It makes an interesting reading.   But today, with employers comfortably ensconced in the labor-market driver's seat, hiring decisions based on instinct are practically unheard of. Indeed, it's not at all unusual these days for a candidate to be grilled by six, eight, or even a dozen interviewers on various rungs of the corporate ladder as part of the overall screening process, say human-resources executives, headhunters, and other experts in modern hiring practices  "Many companies have made bad hires; now it's their market, and they're determined to find the people they want," explains Marie Raperto of the Cantor Concern, a New York City recruiting firm. "Even someone seeking a mid-level job has to be prepared to go through six or seven interviews," she adds. "It's endless."  "You can't even get nine people to agree on where to go for lunch," he adds. "How can you expect them to agree on a person?" But in an age where companies routinely boast about their teamwork ethos, nonhierarchical cultures, and commitment to "cross-functional" collaboration, it's easy to see why consensus now plays a major role in hiring. Many companies known for attracting top-flight talent say they believe that gathering a wide variety of perspectives is essential to ensuring that the right person gets the job.  Problems with group hiring arise when junior staffers or peers are given veto power in the final decision, says Bob Woodrum, a partner at executive-recruiting giant Korn/Ferry International. Recounting a recent incident in which a candidate was dismissed by a Fortune 100 client despite having favorably impressed 11 of 12 interviewers, he notes that "everyone has a different agenda," and that such agendas - whether personal or political - can conflict with the organization's best interests. "This was a case where 11 people had said, 'This guy's a hire.' But one person said the candidate wasn't enthusiastic enough, and that was it."  Read the whole article  urlLink Here . 


</post>

<date>02,July,2003</date>
<post>


       Google Prank    urlLink Google  has played yet another neat prank. Not sure how long this will last though. So, do rush to Google home page, type "Weapons of Mass Destruction" and hit the "I'm Feeling Lucky" button.  Read the error message text CAREFULLY !!  


</post>

<date>02,July,2003</date>
<post>


       Origami Boulders   I came across this hilarious site selling Origami Boulders. Origami is a Japanese art of folding paper. What they are selling is wadded up paper or something like that. The amusing part is the sarcastic way. Interesting are the dealings with the post office and banks. The site promises free shipment (though God only knows who would like to order wadded up paper). Its a laughing riot all the way. Check it out. The site title bears the name  urlLink Origami Boulder Company -- Original Origami Gifts! . Check out this excerpt from the site:  "Site is real. You order and you really get origami boulder artwork with special card to display at your home or workplace. Make good unforgettable gift for friends!  You buy wadded paper boulder and keep it. Or send many to your friends as very nice gift that no one ever forget! I include special card with every order that explain work of art. You buy 20, I send you free extra one with special message from me!  Hurry up and order now!  I send you wadded paper with Priority Mail. It is fast with nice free box from Post Office. Post office worker tell me, 'Don't take so many free boxes! You must order them online from USPS! Other customers mad when you take them all!' I laugh and yell, 'It says free, bureaucrat!! What you expect, dumb dumb?'  Update!!!! Wall Street Journal article on 5/29/02 say that Priority Mail is ripoff and doesn't arrive faster than First Class mail. This is outrage from post office lazy people. I complain today at post office and they laugh and pretend article isn't true. Who you believe, slow postman or Wall Street Journal? Now maybe I buy special boxes and send First Class instead of wasting money on Priority Mail. I make most efficient decision for customer benefit.  My friend is graphic designer for big company. She design page for me because FrontPage too hard for wadded paper artist!  I change design and she send email that says, "you've ruined my beautiful site!!! :O( what in the hell is up with origami boulder?!?!?!?!"  I tell her, "You designer, not site owner! I change whatever I like. You get paid, didn't you? Then go away now!!!" Her design have too many pages and Jakob Nielsen say Internet people too lazy to click so I make everything one page.  


</post>

<date>02,July,2003</date>
<post>


       Seth Godin   Came across the blog site  urlLink Seth's Blog . Seth writes in an iconoclastic manner, complete with tangential thoughts and lateral humor; thus living up to his strature of the ultimate entrepreneur of the year and a marketing guru. I think this blog is going to be added in my everyday-visits site list. Check it out. Its amazing. Herez an article from his site, that he posted:   Naming a business  Greg Harrington writes, "I’ve been thinking quite a bit about a topic lately—how to best name a business—and in looking for some ideas, I’ve reviewed several of your books, but don’t find anything in the way of a thorough treatment of this topic."  Here's what I think: First, the main point: a brand name is a peg that people use to hang all the attributes of your business. The LESS it has to do with your category, the better. If you call yourself International Postal Consultants, there's a lot less room to hang other attributes. Some names I like? Starbucks. Nike. Apple.  Second, please pick a real english word, or a string of them. Axelon and Altus are bad. Jet Blue, Ambient and Amazon are good.  Third, be sure it's easy to spell AND pronounce. Prius is a bad name. I can't tell anyone to buy a Prius because I'm embarrassed I'll say it wrong.  Fourth, don't obsess about getting a short web name. If you want to name your venture capital firm Nickel (a great name, imho) then you could have www.NickelVenture.com and that would be fine. The only way this turns into a problem is if the current owner of the URL is a competitor (which won't happen if you pick a non-obvious name, as I write in #1 above).  If you follow these pieces of advice, you'll discover that there are literally millions of names available to you (lemonpie, for example, is perfect for a scuba tour company. So are orangepie, melonpie and kiwipie). You will have far fewer trademark hassles. You will have no trouble coming up with a cool name that means nothing and makes it easy for you to hang a good brand upon. And you'll have fun.  BUT, don't forget to come up with a great tagline. "lemonpie, the easy way to learn scuba," for example.  PS a couple more tricks:  1. Use a stock photo CD and find cool pictures that match your name BEFORE you pick the name. If you can find a bunch of $30 images that work with a name, grab the pictures, then the name.  2. Don't listen to anyone else. All your friends will hate it. GOOD. They would have hated Starbucks too (you want to name your store after something from Moby Dick!??) If your friends like it, run. 


</post>

<date>02,July,2003</date>
<post>


       Schools of the Future    urlLink Ode  Magazine's latest issue sports an article written by the famous  Ben Okri  on the "Schools of future". He writes that in the future, centres of learning will teach at least one thing we do not teach today: the art of self-discovery. There is nothing more fundamental in education. We turn out students from our universities who know how to give answers, but not how to ask questions.   A really well written article. I hope we would analyse the shortcomings mentioned there, and strive to improve the educational models we currently have, imbibing new ideas and new paradigms into our present systems.


</post>

<date>02,July,2003</date>
<post>


       IT Firms Slash Entry Level Salaries    urlLink Economic Times  reports that though most companies are moving towards performance-linked compensation packages or a variable pay model, industry estimates suggest that entry level salaries have been cut by 20-25% across major companies. Even as this happens, companies are rewarding top performers by increasing their pay. “While companies in the US selectively reduce salaries to fund the bonus pool, companies in India are also following suit,” said a CFO at a leading Indian software company.  Though it is not known whether a 20-25% cut in entry level salaries would be enough to fund bonus reserves and other allowances, sources in top rung companies state that since the measure will be across the board, it would lead to substantial benefits.  The market is looking forward to the first quarter results, beginning with MphasiS. Infosys is slated to announce its results the next day. “All eyes will be on Infosys, which has taken strong measures to further cut costs. These measures, which include cuts in entry level compensation, onsite rationalization of salary-related allowances and a focus to shift work offshore, would reflect in the coming quarters. But the cost-push pressures from offshore salary hikes could be more immediate, when seen together with a weakening dollar and rate declines,” an analyst at Credit Lyonnais Securities said in his report.  Read the full report  urlLink Here 


</post>

<date>02,July,2003</date>
<post>


</Blog>
```

Upon further debugging, the issue seems to when`tree= ET.parse(filename)` is called however I still can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: can you provide a sample of the xml? I think the problem is with root.findall('post')

Comment: @Jonah Added. Funny thing is, when I run the doc_parser(root) only on one file it works, when I try on all 19k I have there is the issue above.

Comment: fwiw I have no issues running your code snippet on your sample xml copied into 20k files, once I remove the unclosed <post> at the end. Is this a cut paste error or an actual example? Because that's not valid xml.

Comment: Whoever advised you to use exception handling this way ought to be flogged in public place - this is actually __worse__ than no exception handing at all. Of course you "can't figure what's the issue is" : you have just made sure you silenced every possible help you could get from the exception message and traceback.

Comment: @jonah what do you mean exactly 'once I remove the unclosed <post> at the end'? It an actual corpus which I downloaded through this link: https://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~koppel/BlogCorpus.htm

I'm trying to perform some sort of classification on this corpus to see which author is male and which is female based on the text and words used

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers what would you suggest? I asked in my previous post and thats what they suggested ... without the try/except I get the following error:     `source = open(source, "rb") FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1005545.male.25.Engineering.Sagittarius.xml'` Yet that file name is in my directory.  Whilst if I split and remove the '.xml' extension this is what I get: `source = open(source, "rb") TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple`

Comment: Of course the file is not found, cf my answer.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers just replied to your answer. Still getting an error

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is here:

```
path = os.listdir(directory)
for filename in path:
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
```

`os.listdir()` returns a list of **names**, not full path. So `ET.parse()` tries to open a file by that name **in the current working directory**, not in `directory`.

You want:

```
filenames = os.listdir(directory)
for filename in filenames:
    filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename) 
    tree = ET.parse(filepath)
```

Also, this:

```
    try:
        tree = ET.parse(filename)
        root = tree.getroot()
        doc_parser(root)
    except:
        print("ERROR ON FILE: {}".format(filename))
```

is the worst thing you could do. This will actually prevent you from knowing what went wrong and where, so you cannot debug your code at all.

Proper exception handling guidelines:

1/ **NEVER EVER** use a "bare" except clause, always specify the exact exception(s) you are expecting at this point. For a top-level "catch all" handler, at least restrict your except clause to `Exception`, so you don't catch `SystemExit`.

2/ Have the narrower possible `try` block (have as few code as possible here). This is to make sure you know where the exception you are handling was effectively raised, so if two statements raises the same exception type for unrelated reasons, you only catch the one you expected.

3/ only catch exception you can actually and effectively handle at this point of the code. If you cannot handle the exception at this point, just let it propagate (or report it with additionnal informations and re-raise it).

4/ Never assume anything about what really happened. Use the exception message **and the traceback** when reporting the exception. The stdlib's `logging` module makes it a breeze (well, once you've learned to properly configure your logger which can be a bit of a PITA xD).

Here what you want is something like:

```
    try:
        tree = ET.parse(filepath)
    except ET.ParseError as e:
        # using `logging.exception()` would be better,
        # but we don't really need the whole traceback here
        # as the error is specific enough and we already
        # know where it happens
        print("{} is not valid XML: {}".format(filepath, e))
        continue 

    root = tree.getroot()
    doc_parser(root)
```

Comment: Upon using your suggestion, a new error prompts:     `self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)

  File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 655, column 788`


My function `clean_dir` is as follows: 

`def clean_dir(directory):
    for filename in filenames:
        filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename) 
        print(filepath)
        tree = ET.parse(filepath)
        root = tree.getroot()
        doc_parser(root)
        print("x")`

Comment: This is a totally unrelated issue  - one of your files is not valid XML. You want to catch and report those errors - but ONLY those errors, cf my edited answer.